# Какое окончание будет правильным? и почему?

Tags: словообразование

Предложение: Но вот край чаши, обращенн (ой,ый) к востоку, начинает розоветь, сползает чернота с широких крон сосен, сквозь космы тумана проглядывает яркая зелёная хвоя.

Answer (score 6):

Окончание причастия проверяем вопросом от сушествительного. *Край какой? обращенный к востоку*. Но если это не край обращен к востоку, а вся чаша (?) , то *край чаши какой? обращенной*. Но что-то я смысл не совсем понимаю. Может все-таки *край чащи?* Тогда *край какой? обращенный*

Comment: Вот авторский текст: только на
дне долины,  похожей на широкую чашу,  вдавленную в горы, глухо звучит
водопад да погромыхивает горная речка.
     Но вот  край  чаши,  обращенный  к  востоку,  начинает  розоветь,
сползает чернота с высоких елей и широких  крон  сосен,  сквозь  космы
тумана  проглядывает  яркая  зеленая хвоя;  заря разгорается,  смывает
ночь,  наполняет долину до краев золотистым светом, возвращает вереску
его дневной сиреневый цвет.     К чему ставим вопрос?

Comment: Край какой? обращенный. Вы правы.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь, судя по тексту, к востоку обращена не вся чаша, а лишь её край (м. р.), следовательно и окончание должно быть мужского рода: *обращённый к востоку*.

Comment: спасибо, у меня такая же точка зрения, и дочь написала в диктанте также, но учительница исправила окончание на "ой", стрелкой показав на связь со словом "чаша". Дело в том, что это единственная ошибка....более того, я нашла первоисточник, произведение Воскресенской с этим текстом, в авторском варианте - " край чаши, обращеннЫЙ,..".Могу ли я отстоять вариант с окончанием "ЫМ"? или тут спорное согласование, которое можно интерпретировать двояко?

Comment: Чаша здесь, как понимаю, - низина в лесу. Как низина может быть обращена на восток, даже представить себе не могу. Тем более, если в первоисточнике именно "обращённый", то идите смело.

Comment: Да, все в пользу ученика.

Comment: Спасибо, можно ли мне ссылку на правило относительно составного определяемого слова перед причастным оборотом? чем руководствоваться в подобных случаях?

Answer (score 2):

Согласна с Ларf. Речь о крае.
Но не могу не согласиться и бегемотусом.
От "долина в форме чаши" вспоминаются "шакалы в форме змеи".

Answer (score 1):

Да, речь идёт о крае. Не зря в начале даётся информация о том, что это за чаша.

Answer (score 1):

> составного определяемого слова

Этот зверь науке не известен.

А правило здесь только одно. Оборот согласуется с определяемым словом. 
Если Вы будете отстаивать правильность написания ЫЙ, то Ваша задача - убедить оппонента в том, что определяемое слово - край, а это вытекает не из какого-то правила, а из смысла предложения. 
Увы, но авторский текст настолько далек от жизни, что позволяет сделать вывод и о том, что к востоку обращена и сама чаша, а не её край. 
Если бы автор имел хоть немного воображения, он бы знал, что в долине рассвет сперва приходит на ***западный*** край.

А а то, каким образом долина (обычно - узкая низменная полоска вдоль реки) может быть похожа на чашу - это только в дурдоме могут сказать.

ЗВ Читали бы уж лучше Чехова. Вот уж у кого природа точна до мельчайших деталей.